# Is it bad to use the property zoom?

Tags: html, css

I would like to use the 'zoom' property to make bigger the content of the page for the mobile devices with high DPI. I know that the firefox doesn't support it. But If it works good for safari and chrome is ok for me.
I saw some recommendations not to use it.

Should I use zoom property?

Comment: It's bad if you use it for your overal layout. But good for eg. tiny icons or similar things that can be adjusted with zoom to fit in a pattern

Comment: `zoom` is Non-standard method of scaling content. Instead of this you can use `scale()`. Also When both zoom and transform: scale() are applied, Chrome will perform zooming operation twice.

Answer (score 1):

Zoom is a non-standard method of scaling content
https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom

Check media queries to change size of an element for mobile
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/